# Alternative to offline access permission for accessing a users profile on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has deprecated the **offline access** permission.As a developer is there some other way for me to post on the wall of a user when he is not online or I can do that only when he is accessing my app?

Answer (score 4):

You can increase 2 table columns in your app namely short_access_token & long_access_token.

Once user authenticates your app, an access token is generated, store it in short_access_token. Then pass this access token to:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN

Once you run this, an access token with 60 days validity will be generated. Store it in long_access_token. Now, use this long_access_token for 60 days.

You can generate long lived access token only once a day i.e. the first time. Use this long lived access token to post on user's wall (if you've already got the permission).

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: +1 helpful, Can you please further explain your statement "You can generate long lived access token only once a day".

Answer (score 2):

You can post to a users wall, without that user being logged in, for up to 60 days. After that, you will need to force the user to login to Facebook again and get a new 60 day access token.

To do all this gracefully, you should store the date of the acquisition of the token in your DB, and set up the necessary UI for the user as that date approaches.

In addition, if the user is an infrequent user of your application, you should really test the validity of the token at least once a day, and go redirect them to login to Facebook if your app finds that the token has expired. This also helps re. tokens becoming invalid due to the user changing their Facebook password.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can post to a user’s wall as long as you have a valid access token – no matter if they are “online” or not.

Stuff to read (clearly looks like you didn’t do much research of your own before asking):

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/