# Keep data from Social Sign In updated even if user doesn't return to site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, linkedin-api, facebook-login

We are using "Sign In with LinkedIn" in our website and we are in the process of adding Facebook Login. I was asked to figure out how to keep the info from the users updated after they login (even if they don't come back to the site) and I'm not sure whether this is possible, or for how much time we are able to access their profile info.

If a user logs in and changes his profile info a month later is it possible to know it even if they don't Sign In again? Could I run a cron job that uses Facebook and LinkedIn APIs to update the users data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Note: The following answers are related to Facebook API only (I've never used LinkedIn API before, but I'm pretty sure the answer can give a brief overview about the problem).***

---

> If a user logs in and changes his profile info a month later is it
>   possible to know it even if they don't Sign In again?

Yes. It is possible to change a user's profile info later, without signing in again. Actually, it depends on the time of the info you're willing to access. If it is a publicly available info (that doesn't need an Access Token), you can easily fetch it from the Facebook API (assuming you are storing the user ID or username in your application when a user first logs in) whenever you want.

However, if it is something which requires an Access Token, then you might need to ask user to login again (since a [User Access Token expires within 2 hours](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)). You can also generate a [Long Lived User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#long-via-code), which typically expires in 60 days. This means that you can request for a user's info from the Facebook API, without needing them to sign in again, within those 60 days.

---

> Could I run a cron job that uses Facebook and LinkedIn APIs to update
>   the users data?

Yes. You can create a Cron Job using your application to fetch the updated info just like I mentioned in the answer to your previous info. Facebook used to provide a similar functionality few years back using a special `offline_access` permission, [but it has been deprecated and cannot be used anymore](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/).

Several alternative methods to it (for example: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231515/alternative-to-offline-access-permission-for-accessing-a-users-profile-on-facebo) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187604/facebook-full-permission-accesstoken-alternative-to-offline-access-token)) can be found by a simple Google search and almost all will discuss the method which I just mentioned in the answer above. Take a look at the [answers to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217564/facebook-php-post-to-fan-page-with-cronjob) for more info on the creation of a Cron Job for Facebook API.

Comment: Hi Rahil, thanks for your answer. I'm really hoping to get some info about how this works in Linkedin, I haven't been able to found any. If you can find something about it I'll accept the answer

Comment: @Liso22 I've actually used the LinkedIn API, so I don't actually know how it works. But you can create your own custom cron job for it as well since the expiry time for a linkedIn access token is 60 days as well. http://developer.linkedin.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-refreshing-access-token. You might find the LinkedIn API documentation helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Basically @Rahil gave a good explanation what you can do. It's important to exchange the short-lived Access Token to a long-lived one, ideally right during the signup process.

What info you can query/update is determined by the permissions you request during the Login, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

A functionality that wasn't mentioned before are the so-called `Realtime Updates`. Have a look at the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.0

Basically you need to setup a service which is reachable for Facebook, and FB then will send a request to this service with the info which field/connection was updated by which user (actual data/the changes themselves are NOT send). You then need to use this info to form a Graph API request and gather the actual changed data yourself.

Be aware that not all fields/connections can be accessed and used by the Realtime Updates API.

Comment: I was really hoping to get the similar info about linkedin. I found some domcumentation about this features in facebook haven't been able to find any info about it in Linkedin. Do you have any idea how this works there?